# O que está errado no código javascript?'

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que o código calcule a area e o perímetro de um retângulo, alguém pode me dizer onde estou falhando.

```
let retangulo = {
    largura: parseInt(prompt('Informe a largura do retângulo:')),
    comprimento: parseInt(prompt('Infomr o comprimento do retângulo'))
}

function calcularArea(){
    let aera;
    area = largura * comprimento;            
    return area;
}

function calcularPerimetro(){
    let perimetro;
    perimetro = 2*(largura + comprimento)
    return perimetro;
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que estás tendo? O código parece ok...

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando variáveis que não existem, que na verdade são propriedades de um objeto. Idealmente, passe o objeto como parâmetro e acesse a propriedade do objeto. Assim:

```js
let retangulo = {
    largura: parseInt(prompt('Informe a largura do retângulo:')),
    comprimento: parseInt(prompt('Infomr o comprimento do retângulo')),  
}

function calcularArea(rect){
    return rect.largura * rect.comprimento;            
}

function calcularPerimetro(rect){
    return 2*(rect.largura + rect.comprimento)
}

console.log(calcularArea(retangulo))
console.log(calcularPerimetro(retangulo))
```